# Is there any API to download Xamarin test cloud run snapshots?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud

I have a script which sends UI automation to test cloud and reads command output. What I would like to do is after test run finishes, download all the snapshots from test cloud. Then I can have script which runs locally to do some post verification without having someone go to the site and view each image manually. Do you know if this is possible?

Thanks,

Comment: I do not believe that feature is available in the Rest API (at least it was not a while back). I had a client who wanted that also and they did not get a reply concerning it is was on the future enhancement list. I did it using an F# Data HTML Type Provider to parse all the image links from the web pages.

Comment: wow, thanks SushiHangover, that is going to be some work to retrieve web content and parse links.

Comment: It is currently planned according to: https://testcloud.ideas.aha.io/ideas/XTA-I-117